# Connect configure stripe addon for Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin

I have installed the latest versions of Gravity Forms and the Stripe addon. I can connect to stripe no problem (the logs there say its been authorised) but when I am redirected to the settings page for Stripe its says I am connected but there are no fields available to configure. So way of adding public keys etc and web hooks.

I have deactivated, re-installed the plugin, logged in and out and still nothing.

Has anybody run into this issue before? Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: I would check for other plugin conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Having checked all the usual suspects, mainly plugin conflicts and still no resolution I reached out to the Gravity Forms support team. Very quickly. they came back with a solution.

In some cases there was a fatal error - see below from their change log

> Fixed a fatal error which can occur with the Stripe API Client if the
> add-on isn't connected to a Stripe account

In any case when I replaced the stipe addon plugin with the new newer version it worked as expected.